# Select html element in yui

Tags: yui

How can I select html element or div by Id using yui , How can I migrate the following code from Jquery to YUI

jQuery("#resultTable").text("");

Where resulttable is a div.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice table comparing YUI3 and jQuery here: http://jsrosettastone.com/

As you can see, it looks very similar:

```
// jQuery
jQuery('#resultTable').text('');

// YUI
Y.one('#resultTable').set('text', '');
```